# How to properly use indexable in Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, r-tree

In this example, I wrote two methods for allowing `rtree.query` to work:

1. A Specialization of `indexable` for the `Entity<float>`
2. A method wrapper

Which one would be better in this case?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
#include <random>

#define METHOD_WRAPPER 0
#define SPECIALIZATION 1
#define SOLUTION METHOD_WRAPPER

using point = boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<float>;

template<typename T, typename IndexableGetter=boost::geometry::index::indexable<T>>
class Collection {
public:
    using box = boost::geometry::model::box<point>;
    void insert(T const& t) { rtree.insert(t); }
    auto begin() const { return rtree.begin(); }
    auto end() const { return rtree.end(); }
    auto find(auto const& search, float radius) {
        std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T const>> result;
        rtree.query(boost::geometry::index::satisfies([&](auto const& el) {
            return boost::geometry::distance(el.position, search) < radius ;
        }), std::back_inserter(result));
        return result;
    }

private:
    boost::geometry::index::rtree<T, boost::geometry::index::quadratic<32>, IndexableGetter> rtree;
};


template<typename T>
struct Entity {
    using result_type = point;
    point position;
    Entity(T x, T y) : position(x, y) {}
#if SOLUTION == METHOD_WRAPPER
    struct ByPosition {
        using result_type = point;
        result_type const& operator()(Entity const& boid) const { return boid.position; }
    };
#endif
    operator sf::Vector2f() const { return sf::Vector2f(position.x(), position.y()); }
};

#if SOLUTION == SPECIALIZATION
namespace boost { namespace geometry { namespace index {

template<>
struct indexable<Entity<float>> {
    using result_type = point;
    result_type operator()(Entity<float> const& e) const {
        return result_type(e.position);
    }
};

}}}
#endif

int main() {
    using Entity = Entity<float>;

    #if SOLUTION == METHOD_WRAPPER
    Collection<Entity, Entity::ByPosition> collection;
    #elif SOLUTION == SPECIALIZATION
    Collection<Entity> collection;
    #endif

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        collection.insert(Entity(
            static_cast<float>(rand() % 100),
            static_cast<float>(rand() % 100))
        );

    for (auto& el : collection)
        std::cout << el.position.x() << ", " << el.position.y() << std::endl;

    auto result = collection.find(point(50, 50), 30);
    for (auto& el : result)
        std::cout << el.get().position.x() << ", " << el.get().position.y() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case they are (obviously?) exactly equivalent. The `indexable` trait merely makes the indexable-getter the default for the element type.

You can make that more obvious by removing the duplication:

```
template <typename T> struct bgi::indexable<Entity<T>> : Entity<T>::ByPosition {};
```

This improves on your specialization by being generic for all `T` instead of hardcoding `T = float`. Using a simplified version of your code to demonstrate side-by-side:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/016cc59b8214331c)**

```cpp
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = bg::index;
using point   = bg::model::d2::point_xy<float>;

template <typename T, typename IndexableGetter = bgi::indexable<T>> class Collection {
  public:
    using value_type = T;

    void insert(T const& t) { rtree.insert(t);      }
    auto begin() const      { return rtree.begin(); } 
    auto end() const        { return rtree.end();   } 

    auto find(auto const& search, float radius) {
        std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T const>> result;
        rtree.query(
            bgi::satisfies([&](auto const& el) { return bg::distance(el.position, search) < radius; }),
            back_inserter(result));
        return result;
    }

  private:
    // using box = bg::model::box<point>;
    bgi::rtree<T, bgi::quadratic<32>, IndexableGetter> rtree;
};

template <typename T> struct Entity {
    point position;
    Entity(T x, T y) : position(x, y) {}

    struct ByPosition {
        using result_type = point;
        constexpr result_type const& operator()(Entity const& boid) const { return boid.position; }
    };
    // operator sf::Vector2f() const { return sf::Vector2f(position.x(), position.y()); }
};

template <typename T> struct bgi::indexable<Entity<T>> : Entity<T>::ByPosition {};

template <typename Coll> void foo(int seed) {
    std::cout << "\n" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    using Entity = Coll::value_type;

    auto dist = bind(std::uniform_int_distribution(0, 99), std::mt19937(seed));
    auto gen  = [&] { return Entity(dist(), dist()); };
    auto dump = [](auto caption, auto const& ee) {
        std::cout << " -- " << caption << ":\t";
        for (auto sep = " "; Entity const& el : ee)
            std::cout << std::exchange(sep, ", ") << bg::dsv(el.position);
        std::cout << "\n";
    };

    Coll coll;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        coll.insert(gen());

    dump("coll", coll);
    dump("result", coll.find(point(50, 50), 30));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        coll.insert(gen());

    dump("coll", coll);
}

int main() {
    using Entity = Entity<float>;

    foo<Collection<Entity, Entity::ByPosition>>(42);
    foo<Collection<Entity>>(42);
}
```

Printing e.g.

```
void foo(int) [with Coll = Collection<Entity<float>, Entity<float>::ByPosition>]
 -- coll:    (79, 37), (18, 95), (77, 73), (59, 59), (44, 15)
 -- result:  (59, 59)
 -- coll:    (79, 37), (18, 95), (77, 73), (59, 59), (44, 15), (9, 15), (45, 5), (33, 86), (14, 60), (65, 70)

void foo(int) [with Coll = Collection<Entity<float> >]
 -- coll:    (79, 37), (18, 95), (77, 73), (59, 59), (44, 15)
 -- result:  (59, 59)
 -- coll:    (79, 37), (18, 95), (77, 73), (59, 59), (44, 15), (9, 15), (45, 5), (33, 86), (14, 60), (65, 70)
```

### Benefits Of Either Approach

The trait makes it easier to default, so if you have generic code that should be able to figure out a suitable indexablegetter, that's your ticket. You might also want to be able to reuse the getter for any entity template instantiation: [Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/876c0945847432ab):

```
struct GetPosition {
    using result_type = point;
    template <typename T> point const& operator()(Entity<T> const& e) const { return e.position; }
    template <typename T> point const& operator()(Resource<T> const& r) const { return r.position; }
};

template <typename T> struct bgi::indexable<Entity<T>> : GetPosition {};
```

That said, if you want to express the intent that the user of `Collection` needs to choose between different getters available, it may be best to **not** default to a single getter. See also: [The Pit Of Success](https://blog.codinghorror.com/falling-into-the-pit-of-success/) design guide.